# Why does "bundle exec fastlane android" execute code inside the ios platform block as well?

Tags: ruby, react-native, fastlane, fastfile

We have a React Native app that we build using Fastlane.

Everything works ok, but when we were optimising our Fastfile we noticed that code inside the ios platform block is executed as well when specifying android and vice versa.

The lanes are called correctly so if we specify "android" only android lanes are executed.

It also feels like the Fastlane documentation doesn't contain any information about this platform blocks.

Here a simplified version of our **Fastfile**.

```
fastlane_version '2.176.0'

puts "STEP >> FASTFILE"

before_all do |lane, options|
  puts "STEP >> BEFORE_ALL"
end

platform :ios do |options|
  puts "STEP >> PLATFORM :IOS"
  lane :build do |options|
    puts "STEP >> PLATFORM :IOS >> LANE :BUILD"
  end
end

platform :android do |options|
  puts "STEP >> PLATFORM :ANDROID"
  lane :build do |options|
    puts "STEP >> PLATFORM :ANDROID >> LANE :BUILD"
  end
end
```

The **command** we execute to call android only:

```
bundle exec fastlane android build platform_env:development
```

Here the **output**:

```
[12:52:55]: STEP >> FASTFILE
[12:52:55]: STEP >> PLATFORM :IOS   ( <-- NOT EXPECTED )
[12:52:55]: STEP >> PLATFORM :ANDROID
[12:52:55]: STEP >> BEFORE_ALL
[12:52:55]: STEP >> PLATFORM :ANDROID >> LANE :BUILD
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, for now we just accepted this weird behaviour.

Comment: Just came across this as well. It's not _bad_, but I'd prefer it not to do so as it's probably going to cause an issue in the future.